# Why does overflow occur in this function when passing an index to slice a string?

Tags: python, recursion, indexing, slice

I have the following function which counts the number of unique palindromes in a string. I am trying to make the algorithm efficient by keeping track of an index to avoid having to call the sliced string each time in the recursion. However when adding an index parameter to the recursive function **cp2** I am getting max calls to the stack. Can someone explain why this is occuring?

```py
def countPalindrones(word, d):
    count = 0

    if word in d:
        return d[word]
    
    if len(word) == 0:
        return 1
    
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if isPalindrone(word[:i+1]):
            count += countPalindrones(word[i+1:], d)
            d[word] = count
    return count

# overflow ???
def cp2(word, index, d):
    count = 0
    
    if word[index:] in d:
        return d[word[index:]]
    
    if len(word[index:]) == 0:
        return 1
    
    for i in range(len(word[index:])):
        if isPalindrone(word[index:][:i+1]):
            count += cp2(word, i + 1, d)
            d[word[index:]] = count
    return count
```

Comment: If you're trying to avoid making lots of slices, why do you write `word[index:]` 6 times in the function instead of saving it in a variable?

Comment: Are you sure your original 'countPalindrones' function is correct? It doesn't seem to count either palindromes or unique palindromes correctly. It might be better to get that working before trying to optimize the runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the recursive calls, you're starting from index `1`, rather than  incrementing from `index`. The recursion should be:

```
count += cp2(word, index + i + 1, d)
```

Also, instead of writing `i + 1` in the loop, you can start your range from `1`, instead of `0`.

```
    for i in range(1, len(word[index:])):
        if isPalindrone(word[index:][:i]):
            count += cp2(word, i, d)
            d[word[index:]] = count
```